# How to iterate nodes properly

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to iterate through my nodes in D3 but I'm struggling because the `datum` parameter always seems to be `undefined` if I use the built in functions. An example of the snippets that I've tried:

```
d3.selectAll(nodes.enter())
  .each(function(d) { 
   console.log(d);
});
```

I've also tried removing the `enter()` to operate on all nodes but I'm facing the same issue. If I change my code however to use a typical creation approach for DOM elements:

```
nodes.enter().append("div")
             .attr("class", function(d) { 
                 console.log(d);
});
```

Then it works fine and displays the following output:

[image]

I guess I must be calling it wrong somehow, but I can't find a decent example and the documentation isn't quite clear enough for me to spot the mistake if I'm doing something wrong. Here's a quick link to the docuemntation on [each()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.each()` function is defined on D3 selections, so there's no need to select an existing selection again. However, `.each()` is not defined on `.enter()`.

```
var sel = d3.selectAll("div").data([1,2,3]);

sel // .each() is defined, but the selection is empty
sel.enter() // .each() is not defined on .enter()

sel.enter().append("div").html(function(d) { return d; });

sel.each(function(d) { // now .each() is defined and the selection
                       // contains the new elements
  console.log(d);
});
```

If you want to iterate over just the data, you can do this in the following hacky way for the enter selection, diving into D3's internal data structures:

```
sel.enter()[0].forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(d.__data__);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately `each()` is undefined if calling it from `nodes.enter()`. If I call it directly on `nodes` then the function never gets called.

Comment: Ah, you're right -- `.each()` isn't defined on `.enter()`, but should work fine otherwise. What is `nodes` in this context?

Comment: nodes should be a hierarchical data set (from a tree) `var nodes = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });`. The best I've got so far, is I've grabbed the result of appending to the SVG `svg:g` and I'm currently using `each()` on those, but was hoping to do it without a DOM element.

Comment: Yeah - does make sense, still uses a DOM selector `d3.selectAll("div")` but if that's how it needs to be done so-be-it. Thanks Lars

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- `.selectAll()` expects a DOM selector. What else do you want to use?

Comment: The aim was to `each()` over just the data - without necessarily needing any DOM, but to retain the ability to check for enter/exit etc.